# Find absolute maximum and minimum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum of the function $f(x,y)=xy-5y-25x+125$ on the region above $y=x^2$ and on or below $y=27$.

**My solution:**

Critical point: $(5, 25)$

$f$ has a saddle point at $(5, 25)$ so it can't be used to find absolute min/max (correct me if i'm wrong).

Boundary points: $(-5, 0), (5, 0), (0,27)$

$f$ has absolute max of $250$ at $(-5, 0)$

$f$ has absolute min of $-10$ at $(0, 27)$

These are my answers, but the online system (homework portal) doesn't accept them so they may be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong boundary points. The curves $y=x^2$ and $y=27$ intersect at $(\pm 3\sqrt{3},27)$. The points $(\pm 5,0)$ are not in the region at all.

And since you are finding the extrema of a function of two variables, you need to consider points on the entire boundary of the region, not just the "boundary points." So you also need to look at $(x,27)$ for $-3\sqrt{3} <x <3\sqrt{3}$. You many also need to look at $(x,x^2)$ for the same $x$'s, but since the region is above $y=x^2$ probably not.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $ \ (5,25) \ $ constitutes a saddle point for the function, and so would not be an extremum over $ \ \mathbb{R} \ $ , but its role changes in the specified parabolic region.  Having ascertained that there is no critical point in the interior, we next need to check the boundary.

Along the line $ \ y \ = \ 27 \ $ , the function becomes

$$ f(x,y) \ = \ xy \ - \ 5y \ - \ 25x \ + \ 125 \ \longrightarrow \ f(x) \ = \ 27x \ - \ 135 \ - \ 25x \ + \ 125 \ = \ 2x \  - \ 10 \ \ . $$

Since this linear function has no relative extrema, we will evaluate it for now at the endpoints of this portion of the region boundary (noted by **Rory Daulton**)

$$ f(-3 \sqrt{3}) \  = \ 2(-3 \sqrt{3}) \  - \ 10 \  = \ -6 \sqrt{3} \  - \ 10 \ \approx \ -20.39 \ \ ,  $$
$$ f(+3 \sqrt{3}) \    = \ 6 \sqrt{3} \  - \ 10 \ \approx \ +0.39 \ \ .  $$

It isn't entirely clear whether the original problem intended to include the parabolic lower boundary, but we will look at our function on $ \ y \ = \ x^2 \ $ as well.  (I suspect it *should* be included, though: otherwise, the endpoints we  just worked with would not be part of the boundary, meaning there would be *no* absolute extrema for the region, as we shall see.)

On the parabola, the function is

$$  \longrightarrow \ f(x) \ = \ x · x^2 \ - \ 5 · x^2 \ - \ 25x \ + \ 125 \ = \ x^3 \ - \ 5 x^2 \ - \ 25x \ + \ 125 $$ $$ = \ (x - 5)^2 \ · \ ( x+5 ) \ \ . $$

The critical points on this portion of the boundary are found from

$$   f'(x) \  = \ 3x^2 \ - \ 10 x \ - \ 25\ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{10 \ \pm \ \sqrt{400}}{6} \ = \ -\frac{5}{3} \ \ , \ \ 5 , $$

producing the function values

$$   f(5) \ =  \ (5 - 5)^2 \ · \ ( 5+5 ) \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ f(-\frac{5}{3}) \ =  \ (-\frac{20}{3})^2 \ · \ \frac{10}{3} \ = \ \frac{4000}{27} \ \approx \ +148.1 \ \ . $$

So the saddle point at $ \ (5,25) \ $ found in your original analysis is a *relative minimum* on the parabolic section of the boundary.  However, the absolute extrema for the closed parabolic region are

**maximum:**   $ \ f(x,y) \ \ = \ \ \frac{4000}{27} \ $ at $ \ \left( \ -\frac{5}{3} \ , \ \frac{25}{9} \ \right) $

**minimum:**   $ \ f(x,y) \ \ = \ \ -6 \sqrt{3} \  - \ 10 \ $ at $ \ \left( \ -3 \sqrt{3} \ , \ 27 \ \right)  $